DS3231 alternative with alarm reset without MCU
I am looking for a RTC chip which does have alarm feature that generates a signal change on one of its pin and simultaniously the alarm can be reset purely by hardware without the need to clear register or what not.
I found DS3231 which does fulfill the first part but after the alarm is once triggered it needs a MCU to reset it which is not accaptable for my use.
I dont mind using MCU once for the initial configuration but after that i want the circuit to function without it. I do not plan on changing the configuration during run time and therefore it makes no sense for me to keep the MCU in. The circuit would be used to turn on specific output on alarm 1 trigger and disable it on alarm 2 trigger. Think something like simple power socket timer.
It would also be accaptable for me if the alarm trigger would only generate one pulse on a pin and than would automatically return to the default state.
Does someone know if anything like this even exist? Or do you know of different approach that would result in correct behaviour?
Also i should add that the time drift should be as low as possible. Few seconds or even a minutes a year would be accaptable if the time can than be easily corrected.
